# Show more pages in archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to increase the number of pages listed in the tag and category archive page. How do I do that?

I tried this code.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_change_posts_tag');
function limit_change_posts_tag($query){
if ($query->is_tag) {
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 20);
}
return $query;
}
```

But the the thumbnail and the title are not wrapping themselves up.

Comment: Seems like you're in the correct direction. Does this help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/331908

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the way you filter if is a tag page. You should use `is_tag`, as simple as that.

This is how it should look

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'limit_change_posts_tag' ); 

function limit_change_posts_tag($query) {
    if ( is_tag() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 20 );
    }
    return $query;
}
```